# NodeJS request: response undefined

Tags: node.js, request

Res should print json data to console. But returns undefined instead. Printing the error outputs “invalid protocol …”

```
const request = require('request')
const cout = console.log
const url = 'http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX&query=37.8267,-122.4233'
request( {url: url}), (err,res) => { console.log(res) })
```

This is the error i get when i print the error arg

```
Error: Invalid protocol: 127.0.0.1:
    at Request.init (/home/toyo/Dev/Udacity/NodeJS/weather-app/node_modules/request/request.js:458:31)
    at new Request (/home/toyo/Dev/Udacity/NodeJS/weather-app/node_modules/request/request.js:127:8)
    at request (/home/toyo/Dev/Udacity/NodeJS/weather-app/node_modules/request/index.js:53:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/toyo/Dev/Udacity/NodeJS/weather-app/app.js:6:1)
```

I am not sure if it matters but I am running this on parrot os

Comment: There is a syntax error here

Comment: @JohnnyHK I have updated the code

Comment: Also you disclosed an access key, you might want to change it if it should be private.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using Axios instead of request, for the simple reason request is now depreciated.

With axios:

```js
const axios = require('axios');

axios
  .get(
    'http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=XXXXXXXXX&query=37.8267,-122.4233'
  )
  .then((res) => console.log(res.data));
```

The result:

```sh
{
  request: {
    type: 'LatLon',
    query: 'Lat 37.83 and Lon -122.42',
    language: 'en',
    unit: 'm'
  },
  location: {
    name: 'North Beach',
    country: 'United States of America',
    region: 'California',
    lat: '37.806',
    lon: '-122.411',
    timezone_id: 'America/Los_Angeles',
    localtime: '2020-05-10 18:31',
    localtime_epoch: 1589135460,
    utc_offset: '-7.0'
  },
  current: {
    observation_time: '01:31 AM',
    temperature: 19,
    weather_code: 116,
    weather_icons: [
      'https://assets.weatherstack.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0002_sunny_intervals.png'
    ],
    weather_descriptions: [ 'Partly cloudy' ],
    wind_speed: 19,
    wind_degree: 230,
    wind_dir: 'SW',
    pressure: 1013,
    precip: 0,
    humidity: 42,
    cloudcover: 75,
    feelslike: 19,
    uv_index: 8,
    visibility: 16,
    is_day: 'yes'
  }
}
```

I would also highly recommend **removing** your access token in the code you posted. I did test this locally and it has worked.

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/request
- https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error and that's now how you call request.

A quick look at the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request):

```js
request(url, function (error, response, body) {
  console.error(error); // Print the error
  console.log(response); // Print the response object
  console.log(body); // Print the body
});
```

Also note that this package is deprecated

> request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

Comment: I made the changes and it still prints undefined to the terminal

Comment: Try `console.log(error)` to see if you have an error message

Comment: Error: Invalid protocol: 127.0.0.1:

Comment: Check your `url` again.

Comment: I have. I have opened it in fixerfox and it shows the right json data

Comment: No your `url` variable is `127.0.0.1` you need to change it in your code so it's the one you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213584/discussion-between-toyo-u-and-mickael-b).